# Telethon write a message/start a chat after button - bot send message before /start

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm trying to write an access bot with telethon for telegram.

1. User added to the group or join with an invite link.
2. Get restricted and have to push a button.
3. The bot write a simple captcha message like "1+2=?"
4. And if it's right, the person gets unrestricted and if wrong, gets kicked out...

Everything works pretty fine but:
If the new joined and user don't write first "/start", the user doesn't get a message from the bot.

Is there any possibility that the person receives the message anyway?

I've read it is not possible to do that somewhere, but there are bots outside how do that?

Comment: you need to send the captcha into the group since bots can not start new conversations

Comment: But there should be a possibility to do it with a private message ? There are some channels/groups who handle it that way ?

Comment: the only way to do it with private message is that the user /start the bot before joining the group, and as far as I know there are not groups doing things like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect when a user joins with [`events.ChatAction`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.chataction.ChatAction) and restrict them from sending messages immediately with [`client.edit_permissions`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.edit_permissions). In the group, you can let them know with a message with buttons that they have to solve a captcha with the bot in private, which you can react to with [`events.Message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.newmessage.NewMessage).

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, Button, events

bot = TelegramClient(...)

async def main():
    async with bot:
        # Needed to find the username of the bot itself,
        # to link users to a private conversation with it.
        me = await bot.get_me()

        @bot.on(events.ChatAction)
        async def handler(event):
            if event.user_joined:
                # Don't let them send messages
                await bot.edit_permissions(event.chat_id, event.user_id, send_messages=False)

                # Send a message with URL button to start your bot with parameter "captcha"
                url = f'https://t.me/{me.username}?start=captcha'
                await event.reply(
                    'Welcome! Please solve a captcha before talking',
                    buttons=Button.url('Solve captcha', url))

        # Detect when people start your bot with parameter "captcha"
        @bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start captcha'))
        async def handler(event):
            # Make them solve whatever proof you want here
            await event.respond('Please solve this captcha: `1+2 = ?`')
            # ...more logic here to handle the rest or with more handlers...
    
        await bot.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Wow perfect! I think the part of the url button is what I' searchin for. I will test it and give feedback. Thank you alot @Lonami ... for the nice support the last days and also big probs for the nice modul :D

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it solves the question and upvote if it was useful, it helps me and it helps others finding this answer ;)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you again. A short question to understand ... ```?start=captcha'``` does not everytime start if you already has a conversion with the bot open. It should maybe better to put inside the start (if you have two diffrent use cases of /start to dont do that with ````pattern= start captcha``` but with an extra argument to check for the function handler like ```async def handler(event, arg=0): if arg == 0: ... else:``` or did I miss something? Because like I say that also trigger /start and sometimes both ...

Comment: You can make part of the pattern optional with the `?` "operator", such as `( captcha)?`.

Comment: @MaTok Nice answer! I have a similar issue but slightly different in execution. Could you pls help me over here?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164049/telethon-get-response-from-bot-when-started-with-parameter-using-telethon